# Scala object initialization bug

Tags: scala, enumeration

I've found a bug in initialization of "handwritten enumeration" in scala. It is handwritten because it is `sealed case class` and `object SomeCode` that have objects inside.

What is interesting - if `sealed case class` have default values - some dark magic happens.
For example we have "handwritten enumeration" that looks like:

```
sealed case class SomeCode(
  id: String,
  legend: String)

object SomeCode {

  object First        extends SomeCode(id = "First", legend = "first legend")
  object Second        extends SomeCode(id = "Second", legend = "second legend")

  val values = Seq(
    SomeCode.First,
    SomeCode.Second)

  private val CACHE: Map[String, SomeCode] = {
    val ids = values.map(_.id)
    (ids zip values).toMap
  }

  def getById(id: String): Option[SomeCode] = CACHE.get(id)
}
```

And one test:

```
import com.blabla.SomeCode
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, WordSpec}

class SomeCodeTest extends WordSpec with Matchers {
  "SomeCode" should {
    "work properly" in {
      println(SomeCode.First.toString)
    }
  }
}
```

When we call `SomeCode.Fist` the initialization of `object SomeCode` starts. So initialization for `val values` and `private val CACHE` starts too and all fine actually.

But, if we introduce **default** value for our `sealed case class`...:

```
sealed case class SomeCode(
  id: String,
  legend: String = "default legend")
...
object First        extends SomeCode(id = "First")
object Second        extends SomeCode(id = "Second")
```

and run our test now - we will have NPE in `CACHE`.

In test we call `SomeCode.First` - and this value will be `null` in `values`, so `values.map(_.id)` will throw NPE.
If from tests we will call `SomeCode.Second` then `null` will be in `SomeCode.Second`

I know that it is not a good practice to extends `sealed case class`, but   nevertheless it should work properly. Maybe I don't understand something in scala, but currently it looks like a compiler bug for me.

`scalaVersion := "2.11.7"`

Also I create issue in scala-lang: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9929

Comment: Could it be that something is missing in your code examples? Because, with the code given I am unable to reproduce the behavior you describe. In other words: 'Works fine for me'

Comment: @SaschaKolberg is it works fine to you with default value - `legend: String = "default legend")` and not setting this value in extended objects

Comment: no, it doesn't.

Comment: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5366

Answer (score 2):

The problem is happening because when we call `SomeCode.First.toString`, the `SomeCode.First` is ending up as `null` in the following code:

`val values = Seq(SomeCode.First, SomeCode.Second)`

You can check the above to be true by printing the output of values in the REPL.

Interestingly, look at the REPL output with the following code:

```
sealed case class SomeCode(
  id: String,
  legend: String = "default")

object SomeCode {
  println("begin object init")
  object First extends SomeCode(id = "First"){println("initializing First")}
  object Second extends SomeCode(id = "Second"){println("initializing Second")}
  println(SomeCode.First)
  println(SomeCode.Second)
}

SomeCode.First

// REPL Output:
begin object init
null  <--- SomeCode.First is null!!! Why does it not initialize the First object?
initializing Second  <--- Correctly initializes the Second object.
SomeCode(Second,default)
initializing First  <--- Now starts to initialize the First object
res41: SomeCode.First.type = SomeCode(First,default)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the essence of my question. Interesting that if you change First to `object First extends SomeCode(id = "First", "notDefault")` all will be fine; OR rename `object SomeCode {` to something like `object SomeCodes {`

Comment: haha I tried the exact `SomeCodes` variation too and it does work. But don't know whats going on.